# Android animation. Interpolator. What is this?

Tags: android, android-animation, interpolation

I want to use **Android Animation Utils**. I read about this some information, but I cant understand what can I do with **interpolator**... **What is this? Can I create this one?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Interpolator

https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-interpolators-a-visual-guide

https://medium.com/mindorks/understanding-interpolators-in-android-ce4e8d1d71cd

short answer:

An interpolator is a mathematical tool that takes original time instances as an input, performs an operation based on its mathematical equation and provides output as a time instance of a replacement frame for that given input instance.

So basically factor that will determine how your animation will animate.

And you can create your own